# Como retornar uma Promise a partir da resolução de outras?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, promises, ecmascript-5, ecmascript-6

Sou relativamente novo nesse assunto de **Promises**, apesar de já tê-las usado inúmeras vezes, especialmente em requisições AJAX.

Estou construindo uma aplicação front-end que executa em SharePoint e, para conseguir diversas informações sobre o usuário acessando à página, preciso fazer 2 requisições diferentes à API do SharePoint, já que uma URL só não fornece todos os dados que eu preciso.

Para facilitar, estou criando uma lib com diversos métodos para consumo da API para facilitar o reuso da lógica em diversos projetos. Assim, eu queria resumir as duas requisições dos dados do usuário em uma única função, já mesclando os resultados e retornando um único objeto.

Já vi que o `Promise.all()` faz esse papel de esperar múltiplas promises e retornar uma única nova promise, mas o resultado é um array, e queria que eles fossem o objeto mesclado resultante das 2 promises.

E, pra dificultar um pouco, preciso fazer uma lib compatível com o IE, o que elimina a possibilidade de se usar a abordagem Async/Await.

Eis o que tenho:

```
function getUser() {
    var userData1 = axios.get(url + '/web/CurrentUser');
    var userData2 = axios.get(url + '/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties');

    return Promise.all([userData1, userData2]);
}

var userDataAll;
getUser().then(function(values) {
    userDataAll = Object.assign({}, values[0].data, values[1].data);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estudei um pouco melhor as promises e consegui me dar conta da solução: encapsular todo o conteúdo em uma nova promise e chamar o resolve dentro de `Promise.all()`, quando os resultados já tiverem passado pelo `Object.assign()`:

```
function getUser() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var userData1 = axios.get(url + '/web/CurrentUser');
        var userData2 = axios.get(url + '/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties');
        Promise
            .all([userData1, userData2])
            .then(function(results) {
                let userData = Object.assign({}, results[0].data, results[1].data);
                resolve(userData);
            })
            .catch(function(errors) {
                reject(errors);
            });
    });
}
```